# in c# getting Error cannot access a disposed object object name='System.Net.Socket.Socket'

Tags: c#, java

**I want a chat application in C# Client and in Java Server**

I go through C# Client but I got some Error when I response to Java Server I get the error@

> cannot access a disposed object object name='System.Net.Socket.Socket'

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];// data buffer for incoming data

        // connect to a Remote device
        try
        {
            // Establish the remote end point for the socket
            IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.Resolve("localhost");
           IPAddress ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 95);
            Socket Socketsender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            // Connect the socket to the remote endpoint
            Socketsender.Connect(ipEndPoint);

            Console.WriteLine("\n\n___________________Client Server Chat Application__________________________");
            Console.WriteLine("___________________________________________________________________________");
            Console.WriteLine("\nSocket Connecting To Java Server...." + Socketsender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
           // Console.ReadLine();
            string data = null;

            while (true) 
            {
                //Recieved from Java Server Message
                int bytesRec = Socketsender.Receive(bytes);
                Console.WriteLine("\nJava Server:: {0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec));
              //  Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.Write("C# Client  ::"); // Prompt
                    string line = Console.ReadLine();

                    byte[] sendToServer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(line);
                    // Send the data through the socket
                    int intByteSend = Socketsender.Send(sendToServer);
               //  Socketsender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);

                Socketsender.Close();
                               Console.WriteLine("____________________________________________________________________________");
                Console.WriteLine("_________________________End Chat___________________________________________");                  
                // Socketsender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
              Socketsender.Close();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }


}
```

Comment: You need to move SocketSender.Close() out of the loop.

Answer (score 5):

You are closing your socket (`Socketsender`) in he while loop, and then—in the next iteration—calling `Receive` on it.

Once a socket is closed it is dead,<sup>1</sup> and cannot be used for anything. You would need to create a new socket and connect it to the server.

Or better, keep the first socket open.

(You also are performing the close twice, but I'm assuming that is a transcription error.)

---

<sup>1</sup> Insert dead parrot here.

Comment: Socketsender i moved into after while loop but i got same problem ......................................                   .System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'.
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size,
 SocketFlags socketFlags, SocketError& errorCode)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size,
 SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer)

Comment: You need to trace your object lifetimes: don't keep using them after closing or disposing (including `using` block). Without your current code (which if like the code in the Q needs clean up: start with consistent formatting and good naming: clarity is *everything* to programming) all we can do is restate what the exception is already telling you.